# Sql- Subquery with SELECT MAX

Tags: sql

I´ve got this code, but what I need is the MAX of "n_vezes_ganhas". This code shows who took the first place and how many times, but what I want is to see who was more times first.

```
SELECT (remadores.nome) AS remador, (regata.nome) AS regata, 
       COUNT(remadores.cod_remador) AS n_vezes_ganhas
FROM remadores,
     resultados,
     prova,
     regata
WHERE remadores.cod_remador = resultados.cod_remador
  AND resultados.cod_resultado = prova.cod_resultado
  AND prova.cod_regata = regata.cod_regata
  AND resultados.posição = 1  
GROUP BY remadores.nome
```

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Tip of today: switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax - easier to write (without errors), easier to read, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

It subqueries your query and gets the maximum of your computed column.

```
SELECT MAX(c.n_vezes_ganhas) n_vezes_ganhas
FROM
(
SELECT (remadores.nome) AS remador, (regata.nome)AS regata, 
    COUNT(remadores.cod_remador) AS n_vezes_ganhas
    FROM remadores,resultados,prova,regata
    WHERE remadores.cod_remador=resultados.cod_remador
    AND resultados.cod_resultado= prova.cod_resultado
    AND prova.cod_regata=regata.cod_regata
    AND resultados.posição = 1
    GROUP BY remadores.nome
) c
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `ALL`

```
SELECT (remadores.nome) AS remador, 
  (regata.nome)AS regata, 
  COUNT(remadores.cod_remador) AS n_vezes_ganhas
FROM remadores,resultados,prova,regata
WHERE remadores.cod_remador=resultados.cod_remador
  AND resultados.cod_resultado= prova.cod_resultado
  AND prova.cod_regata=regata.cod_regata
  AND resultados.posição = 1
GROUP BY remadores.nome
HAVING COUNT(remadores.cod_remador) >= ALL (
  SELECT COUNT(remadores.cod_remador) AS n_vezes_ganhas
  FROM remadores,resultados,prova,regata
  WHERE remadores.cod_remador=resultados.cod_remador
    AND resultados.cod_resultado= prova.cod_resultado
    AND prova.cod_regata=regata.cod_regata
    AND resultados.posição = 1
  GROUP BY remadores.nome
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you only need to sort you result, you can also add TOP 1 if you only want the highest winner:

```
SELECT TOP 1 (remadores.nome) AS remador, (regata.nome)AS regata, 
      COUNT(remadores.cod_remador) AS n_vezes_ganhas
FROM remadores,resultados,prova,regata
WHERE remadores.cod_remador=resultados.cod_remador
      AND resultados.cod_resultado= prova.cod_resultado
      AND prova.cod_regata=regata.cod_regata
      AND resultados.posição = 1  
GROUP BY remadores.nome   
ORDER BY n_vezes_ganhas DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Then, the answer to your question is an `ORDER BY` with some way to fetch the first row.  The ANSI standard approach is:

```
SELECT rem.nome AS remador, reg.nome AS regata, 
       COUNT(rem.cod_remador) AS n_vezes_ganhas
FROM remadores rem JOIN
     resultados res
     ON rem.cod_remador = res.cod_remador JOIN
     prova p
     ON res.cod_resultado = p.cod_resultado JOIN
     regata reg
     ON p.cod_regata = reg.cod_regata
WHERE res.posição = 1  
GROUP BY rem.nome 
ORDER BY n_vezes_ganhas
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Notice the use of table aliases and qualified column names.  These make the query easier to read and to write.